# Replace filename contained in file and also rename file by new name using java

Tags: java, replace, rename

I've been trying to rename files and folders in a given folder by finding and replacing a substring in their name. Also, the name of file is contained in their contents also. I need to replace it to the new name.

For Example:

> Change "XXX" to "KKK" in all the files and folder names and also in file contents:
>
> Original file name: 0001_XXX_YYY_ZZZ.txt
>
> New file name: 0001_KKK_YYY_ZZZ.txt

Following is the code that I'm using.

When I run the following code without calling the function replaceText(), its renaming the file and folder. But, when I try to change the text of file and then rename the file and folder; contents of file is changed but renaming of both file and folder fails.

Please help.

```
public class FindReplaceAnywhere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String find = "XXX";
        String replace = "KKK";
        String baseLoc = "D:\\0001_XXX_YYY_ZZZ";

        FindReplaceAnywhere obj = new FindReplaceAnywhere();

        File baseLocObj = new File(baseLoc);
        LinkedList<File> baseFolderList = new LinkedList<File>();

        // Add base folder object to list
        baseFolderList.add(baseLocObj);

        // Get list of files in the folder
        for(File file: baseLocObj.listFiles()) {
            baseFolderList.add(file);
        }

        // Rename the files, folders & contents of files
        obj.rename(baseFolderList, find, replace);
    }

    public void rename(LinkedList<File> fileList, String find, String replace) {
        String tempStr = null;
        int beginIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = 0;
        File tempFile;

        System.out.println(">>> Batch Rename Process Begins >>>\n");

        for(File aFile:fileList) {
            // If Object is File, change the text also
            if(aFile.isFile()) {
                replaceText(aFile,find,replace);
            }
        }
    
        for(File aFile: fileList) {
            System.out.println("Processing>>>");
            System.out.println(aFile.getPath());
            if(aFile.getName().contains(find)) {
                // Get the name of File object
                beginIndex = aFile.getPath().length() - aFile.getName().length();
                endIndex = aFile.getPath().length();
                tempStr = aFile.getPath().substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
                tempStr = tempStr.replace(find, replace);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Error: Pattern not found\n");
                continue;
            }
            tempFile = new File(aFile.getParentFile(),tempStr);

            boolean success = aFile.renameTo(tempFile);
            if(success) {
                System.out.println("File Renamed To: "+tempFile.getName());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Error: Rename Failed\nPossible Cause: File is open in another application");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Replace the text of file if it contains filename
     */
    public void replaceText(File file, String find, String replace) {
        String fullText = "";
        String line = "";
        String fileName = "";
        String replaceName = "";

        BufferedReader in;
        BufferedWriter out;

        // Read the file contents
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                fullText+=line+"\n";
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        // Replace the text of file
        fileName = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().indexOf("."));
        replaceName = fileName.replace(find, replace);
        fullText = fullText.replace(fileName, replaceName);

        // Write the replaced text to file
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            out.write(fullText);
            out.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the *exact* problem you're facing? Just saying that it doesn't work will not suffice.

Comment: You should reduce the amount of code to as little as possible, providing the relevant part of it only, cause noone is going to look through like 200 lines of code. Also specify the error you're getting and the line it occurs at.

Comment: See http://sscce.org/ for guidance. @svz It isn't necessarily an exception; it could be just that the code is not doing what is intended.

Comment: Well. I even launched your code and at first glance it seems to do what it is supposed to. Is the problem with some of the edge cases?

Comment: @svz What I guess is that after replacing the text in file and then trying to rename it...the second operation fails because file is locked by the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're closing your input (`in`) file after reading it, which will hold that file open - Under *nix a rename should still work, but it will fail under Windows:

- Use a `finally` block to ensure that the resource is closed.. but only after you're assured that it was opened.

While I'm at it, please allow me to suggest another change to the code:

- Move "declarations" to the the absolute last point in the code where they can be made.. avoid declaring early.  In this case, both `in` and `out` are unnecessarily declared early.  There are others; I'll leave that for you to work out.

So, for the input file:

```
    // Read the file contents
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        // If you got this far, the file is open...
        // use try/finally to ensure closure.
        try {
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                fullText+=line+"\n";
            }
        }
        finally {
          in.close();
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and for the output file:

```
    // Write the replaced text to file
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        try {
            out.write(fullText);
        }
        finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I'd never think that it behaves differently on Win and *nix. What causes that? Couldn't find that on google..

Comment: For Unix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode#Implications; For Windows I can only share my own experiences.  Easy to verify - use "more" on a sufficiently large file, and try to remove it from another command line program.